# Behaviour of Scala underscore not work like element of list

Tags: scala

Hi I am new in scala, and of course have a newbie question,
why the underscore character not work in this cases
my undertanding about underscore in this case it represent one element of the list

```
val listOftuple =  List(("cat","tom"),("mouse","jerry"),("dog","spike"))
val listOfarray =  List(Array("cat","tom"),Array("mouse","jerry"),Array("dog","spike"))

tuplelist.map(it=>it._1+it._2) //Ok 
tuplelist.map(_._1+_._2) //Not work, give me: error: missing parameter type for expanded function

listOfarray.map(_.length) //Here work, like array.length
listOfarray.map(it=>it(0)+it(1)) //Ok

listOfarray.map(_=>_(0)+_(1))//Not work, give me: error: missing parameter type for expanded function 
listOfarray.map(_(0)+_(1))//Not work, give me: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
```

may be i fall in a lexical misunderstanding ?
how to fix the error msg?
greetings

Comment: An underscore can stand in for a passed parameter only once. If there are 2 underscores then it means that the lambda code receives 2 passed parameters.

Comment: when I read _.length, I think _ represent one element of the list. So i can do _(0)+_(1), but how you tell me _ can be passed only once, so please can give the link of the documentation?

Comment: From section 8.5 from [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#i788093512-1)(1st edition): "...you can use underscores as placeholders for one or more parameters, so long as each parameter appears only one time within the function literal." And later in that same section: "Multiple underscores mean multiple parameters, not reuse of a single parameter repeatedly. The first underscore represents the first parameter, the second underscore the second parameter, the third underscore the third parameter, and so on."

Comment: Great Thanks  @jwvh

Answer (score 1):

```
tuplelist.map(_._1+_._2)
```

Each time you use `_`, it stands for another parameter. That is, `_ + _` is equivalent to `(x,y) => x+y`, not `x => x+x`. So the above is equivalent to `tuplelist.map((x, y) => _._1 + _._2)`, which does not work because `map` expects a function that takes only one argument.

```
listOfarray.map(_=>_(0)+_(1))
```

Using `_` as the name of a function parameter just means that the parameter will be ignored. When you use `_` inside the function's body, it is still the function shortcut operator, not a reference to the ignored parameter. So the above lambda is equivalent to `ignoredParam => (x, y) => x + y`.

```
listOfarray.map(_(0)+_(1))
```

`(x,y) => x(0) + y(1)`, but you want `x => x(0) + x(1)`.

> how to fix the error msg?

In all of these cases, using an explicit parameter list is the correct solution. You simply can't use the shortcut notation if you want to use the same parameter more than once.